# Get size of GridView when creating items within its adapter

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to arrange a set of custom widgets inside a GridView. There are predefined templates which describe a count of elements and arrangement config. Max width and heigh for each of them have to be provided in order to avoid scrolling. How can I get a size of the displayed GridView when computing items size in adapter's "GetView" method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you add some code and more info about what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to know the size of the screen, the size of the items inside the GridView or the size of the GridView itself?

Comment: I need to know the size of the GridView

Answer (score 0):

You have access to few functions in order to get a GridView Height and Width as any other View. Look at [the documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view
>   actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These
>   dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see
>   Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by
>   calling [getMeasuredWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth()) and [getMeasuredHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight()).
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes
>   drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual
>   size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These
>   values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width
>   and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling [getWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth())
>   and [getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()).

Try doing a quick search on their doc next time, even if it's Xamarin, the Android doc is pretty reliable and you only need some adjustment to make it work.

(e.g.) : `grivView.Width;` instead of `gridView.getWidth();` one being a property on Xamarin to follow C# standards, the other is a function.